# eledmac and cleveref?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, eledmac

I'd like to use eledmac and cleveref in the same document, but I'm running into trouble with something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
a b c d
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

The error message I get (on every second run with either pdflatex or xelatex) is:

```
! Use of \gl@poff doesn't match its definition.
\actionlines@list ->\expandafter 
                                 \def \csname \@tempc @line@name@plural@prea...

l.7 \beginnumbering
```

If I comment out the cleveref package, it works fine (but I need it in another part of the document).

Can anyone think of a workaround?

This is the list of packages loaded, in case it helps:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 eledmac.sty    2013/12/15 v1.8.1 LaTeX port of EDMAC
   xargs.sty    2008/03/22 v1.1  extended macro definitions  (mpg)
 xkeyval.sty    2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5 Variant command support
 xstring.sty    2013/10/13  v1.7c  String manipulations (C Tellechea)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
cleveref.sty    2013/12/28 v0.19 Intelligent cross-referencing
```

Comment: Seems like a bug, which should be reported via https://github.com/maieul/ledmac. Let’s notify @Maïeul here too.

Comment: yes, please open a tickets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The release 1.10.1, which I have just pushed on CTAN, fixes this problem.